# Width and height information of uploaded image through servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I'm new to Java Servlets and Stackoverflow. I need to store an image in a database as a blob-object. This image must be exactly 300x300px and have a size less than 400kb. The image is uploaded with a html-form.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    final Part filePart = request.getPart("albumthumbnail");

    ImageInfo ii = new ImageInfo();

    ii.setInput(filePart.getInputStream());

    if(filePart != null){
        writer.println(ii.getFormatName());
        writer.println(ii.getHeight());
        writer.println(ii.getWidth());
        writer.println("OK");
        writer.println(filePart.getName());
        writer.println(filePart.getSize());
        writer.println(filePart.getContentType());
    }
```

When I upload a file I get this output:

JPEG 0 0 OK albumthumbnail 1421773 image/png

It looks like the ImageInfo class is using default values instead of the image parameters because I uploaded a png-file.

I don't know if this is the right to obtain the width and height of an uploaded image. Better solutions are always welcome, thanks.

Comment: Where are you `check()`ing the file format? Where are you setting the `setDetermineImageNumber()` to true? http://svn.ckeditor.com/FCKeditor.Java/branches/2.4.x/java-core/src/main/java/org/devlib/schmidt/imageinfo/ImageInfo.java

Comment: I set the setDetermineImageNumber() to true. No result.

Comment: I just tested on my machine and the class works fine.

Comment: So the class is showing the correct information (image width & height) ?

Comment: Yup. Its probably something else wrong with your code and hence a local, limited scope problem.